# What approximation does Tamm-Dancoff approximation (CI singles) correspond to in real time Time-Dependent Density Functional Theory?

Tags: research-level, time-evolution, density-functional-theory

Starting from equations of motion for time-dependent density functional theory (in real time)

$$
    \frac{ {\rm d} \rho_{nn} }{ {\rm d} t} = i \left[ \rho_{nn}^{(1)}, h^{\rm KS} \right]
\quad\text{with}\quad
    h^{\rm KS} = h^{\rm KS, (0)} +  h^{\rm KS,(1)} \ldots
$$

I can eventually derive the commonly known response equation
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\Delta + K  & K \\
K           & \Delta + K
\end{array}
\right]
    \left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
X  \\
Y
\end{array}
\right]
=
\Omega
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
1     &  0 \\
0     &  -1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
X  \\
Y
\end{array}
\right]
- 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
       V_{\rm cos}^{(1)} \\
       V_{\rm cos}^{(1)}
\end{array}
\right],
$$
which corresponds to equation (11.67) of [J. Mol. Struc. THEOCHEM \textbf{914}, 3 (2009)](https://people.ifm.liu.se/panor/courses/Computational_Chemistry/Articles/Casida-THEOCHEM-2009.pdf). Where $\Delta_{ehe'h'}$ is $(\epsilon_{h}-\epsilon_{e})\delta_{ee'}\delta_{hh'}$ and $K_{ehe'h'}$ are the Coulomb integrals. n stands for general Kohn-Sham state index, e for electrons only index and h for holes only index.

This matrix problem can reduced by factor of 2 by Casida approach: 
$$
\Delta^{1/2} (\Delta + 2K) \Delta^{1/2} F = \Omega^2 F 
$$

Widely used [Tamm-Dancoff Approximation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261499011495) (TDA) to TDDFT neglects the off-diagonal coupling term (K) between 'excitations' and 'de-excitations' and one has to just diagonalize $\Delta+K$ to obtain X and Y is assumed to be zero.

So my question is, I can easily find excited states in full TDDFT approximation using real-time propagation method. But what approximation do I have to make in real time in order to obtain Tamm-Dancoff approximation excitations in real time TDDFT?

Comment: 4 years is long to not get an answer, maybe copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1271772 actually now know the answer. If I find time, I'll reply myself :)

Comment: We have a gpaw tag at Matter Modeling SE, can you answer some questions in the gpaw tag? Also we have a TD-DFT tag.

Comment: I do think this question (even self-answered) would fit pretty well on Matter Modeling.